# Elasticsearch NEST 2.x Field Names

Tags: couchbase, nest, elasticsearch-net, elasticsearch-2.0

I am upgrading to NEST 2.3.0 and trying to rewrite all queries that were originally written for NEST 1.x.
I am using the Couchbase transport plugin that pushes data from Couchbase to Elasticsearch.

POCO

```
 public class Park
    {
        public Park()
        {

        }

        public bool IsPublic { get; set; }
    }
```

Mapping is like this

```
"mappings": {
"park": {
            "_source": {
                "includes": [
                  "doc.*"
                ],
                "excludes": [
                  "meta.*"
                ]
            },
            "properties": {
                "meta": {
                    "properties": {
                        "rev": {
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                      "flags": {
                        "type": "long"
                      },
                      "expiration": {
                        "type": "long"
                      },
                      "id": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "index": "not_analyzed"
                      }
                    }
                },
              "doc": {
                "properties": {

                  "isPublic": {
                    "type": "boolean"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
        }
      }
```

Sample document in elasticsearch

```
    {
  "_index": "parkindex-local-01",
  "_type": "park",
  "_id": "park_GUID",
  "_source": {
    "meta": {
      "expiration": 0,
      "flags": 33554433,
      "id": "park_GUID",
      "rev": "1-1441a2c278100bc00000000002000001"
    },
    "doc": {
      "isPublic": true,
      "id": "park_GUID"
    }
  }
}
```

My query in NEST

```
 var termQuery = Query<Park>.Term(p => p.IsPublic, true);
        ISearchResponse<T> searchResponse = this.client.Search<T>(s => s.Index("parkindex-local-01")
                     .Take(size)
                     .Source(false)
                     .Query(q => termQuery));
```

This query goes to Elasticsearch as below

```
{
  "size": 10,
  "_source": {
    "exclude": [
      "*"
    ]
  },
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "isPublic": {
        "value": "true"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It doesn't retrieve any data, it will work only if I prefix the field name with ***"doc."*** so query becomes as below

```
{
  "size": 10,
  "_source": {
    "exclude": [
      "*"
    ]
  },
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "doc.isPublic": {
        "value": "true"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

How do I write the query above in NEST so it can properly interpret the field names, I tried using Nested Query with Path set to "doc", but that gave an error saying field is not of a nested type.

Do I need to change my mapping?

This all used to work in Elasticsearch 1.x and NEST 1.x, I guess this has to do with breaking changes to field names constraints.

Answer (score 0):

[Fields can no longer be referenced by shortnames in Elasticsearch 2.0.](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.0/breaking_20_mapping_changes.html#_fields_cannot_be_referenced_by_short_name)

`isPublic` is a property of the `doc` field, which is mapped as an `object` type, so referencing by the full path to the property is the correct thing to do.

[NEST 2.x has some ways to help with field inference](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/field-inference.html), an example

```
public class Park
{
    public Doc Doc { get; set;}
}

public class Doc
{
    public bool IsPublic { get; set;}
}

var termQuery = Query<Park>.Term(p => p.Doc.IsPublic, true);

client.Search<Park>(s => s.Index("parkindex-local-01")
             .Take(10)
             .Source(false)
             .Query(q => termQuery));
```

results in

```
{
  "size": 10,
  "_source": {
    "exclude": [
      "*"
    ]
  },
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "doc.isPublic": {
        "value": true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You may also want to take a look at the [automapping documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/auto-map.html).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, my type POCO doesn't have a Doc object, IsPublic is a direct property of class Park.

The "doc" in Elasticsearch is there because I use the couchbase transport plugin to move documents from Couchbase to Elasticsearch, my code adds documents to Couchbase then the transport plugin moves the documents from Couchbase to Elasticsearch.

I never index directly in Elastcsearch.

I think the field inference is what I need, how do I use that in the query above though?

Comment: The `park` mapping has two `object` type fields, `doc` and `meta` - the `doc` property will be stored in the `_source` document but `meta` will not be because of `_source` includes/excludes. `meta` fields are still searchable however. Prior to Elasticsearch 2, you could use `IsPublic` as though it were a property directly on `Park` type, but in Elasticsearch 2, you will need to use the full path to the field, `doc.isPublic`. You could change your CLR type to accommodate this as I have above.